# Node.js: How do Proxy sites deal with relative Urls?

Tags: node.js, proxy, screen-scraping, relative-path

I've created a relatively simple proxy in Node, which allows me to download pages and display them. This is fine, although some **scripts**, **links**, **forms** and **images** seem to be broken since they are pointing to relative files. As a project I'm trying to create a fully functional web proxy.

How do sites like [Proxify](http://Proxify.com) solve this problem?

Program for reference:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var request = require('request'),
sys = require('sys'),
fs=require('fs');

app.get('/url', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query.link);

  request({ uri: req.query.link,
            headers: {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows  NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0"}
          }, function (error, response, body) {

             if (error && response.statusCode !== 200) {    
               console.log('Error when contacting google.com')
             }

  res.send(body, {"Content-type": "text/html"});
  res.end(); 

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code is only proxying the html file, and the client is grabbing the rest directly from the real site. You'll want to use something like node jQuery to replace all src/href in the document to make them go through your proxy, and at the same time you can check if they're relative or not and if they are prepend the current url and then create your proxy url.

Comment: Thanks, but what of forms? That's one of the real problems, I'm not sure how to display the result of form data, especially when it's a script that handles the action.

Comment: You'll want to use app.all instead of app.get, then pass through the method used. So if you're using the bodyParser middleware your request options would then be {uri: req.query.link, method: req.method, body: req.body, headers: '...'}

Comment: So how would I be able to catch what is being passed through when a link or form is being processed on the scraped site?

Thanks by the way.

Comment: Just using that option block should take care of passing everything through, you'll get the body back from the POST as you would expect. Check out this paste to see how it would look. http://pastebin.com/ah4nEsTi

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use some forms, but ones that run on javascript will be an issue. I've decided that using REGEX to detect relative URLS  that the script is pointing to would be the best course of action.